# How can I join two queries to get a single output?

Tags: postgresql

First query

```sql
select employee_name_en, count(*)
from fl_file fl
  inner join fl_file_movement movement
     on movement.file_number_fk = fl.file_id
  inner join vw_employee_details_with_department vw
     on vw.post_detail_id = movement.sent_by_post_fk
where  fl.file_nature = 'E'
group by vw.employee_name_en;
```

```
  employee_name_en    | count
-----------------------+-------
CEG USER              |     3
DEEPIKA               |    13
KEERTHI               |    18
RAMESH                |     6
VIJAYA                |     3
```

Second query

```sql
select employee_name_en, count(*)
from fl_correspondence_receipt cr
  inner join fl_correspondence_receipt_movement movement
     on movement.correspondence_receipt_fk = cr.correspondence_id 
  inner join vw_employee_details_with_department vw
     on vw.post_detail_id = movement.sent_by_post_fk 
where  cr.receipt_nature = 'E'
group by vw.employee_name_en;
```

```
  employee_name_en    | count
-----------------------+-------
DEEPIKA               |     5
SNEHAL                |     3
KEERTHI               |     4
RAMESH                |     7
VIJAYA                |     4
```

Comment: How do you want to join them?

Comment: What is the final result needed after outputs join? show it.

Comment: Does Ramesh need to show 13? Or do you expect two columns with different values in each?

Comment: I need two columns with different values in each.

Comment: I need to join the queries to give single output but not adding them.. I need both the count columns with different values each but together in output

Comment: @kruthiprabhu Is using UNION won't solve your problem?

Comment: How about SELECT (query1),(query2) https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f8nZn5LQfbmKxAdxX2fdej/53

Comment: @VishwasAtrey No Union adds up the columns.. I need both the count columns with different values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should output one row per employee name, with two additional columns (file_count and correspondence_count) of the counts from each of your queries. If the employee name didn't have a result in one of the subqueries, that row's corresponding count column will be NULL.

```
SELECT coalesce(t0.employee_name_en, t1.employee_name_en) employee_name_en,
    t0.count file_count,
    t1.count correspondence_count
FROM (select employee_name_en, count(*)
from fl_file fl
  inner join fl_file_movement movement
     on movement.file_number_fk = fl.file_id
  inner join vw_employee_details_with_department vw
     on vw.post_detail_id = movement.sent_by_post_fk
where  fl.file_nature = 'E'
group by vw.employee_name_en) AS t0
FULL OUTER JOIN (
select employee_name_en, count(*)
from fl_correspondence_receipt cr
  inner join fl_correspondence_receipt_movement movement
     on movement.correspondence_receipt_fk = cr.correspondence_id 
  inner join vw_employee_details_with_department vw
     on vw.post_detail_id = movement.sent_by_post_fk 
where  cr.receipt_nature = 'E'
group by vw.employee_name_en
) as t1
ON t0.employee_name_en = t1.employee_name_en;
```

Comment: thank you! Got the output as required.